# jquery datepicker selected not reloading

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have following code to show me the selected day from datepicker:

`<input onFocus="blur();" class="day_selected">`

I have this and the datepicker running multiple times in same page and once the page is reloaded using jquery the input is still there, but no date showing.  In order to show, I have to click on date again on the datepicker and then it shows.

How can I make sure that today's date ALWAYS shows no matter what.

Answer (score 1):

To set the default value of the field to the current date, try this:

```
var currentDate = new Date();
var prettyDate = (currentDate.getMonth() +1) + '/' + currentDate.getDate() + '/' + currentDate.getFullYear();
$(".day_selected").val(prettyDate);
```

Obviously, if the user selects a different date in the control and then refreshes the date will be reset to today. If you need it to maintain state, you'll either need to store the value in a cookie, or send it to a back-end datastore via AJAX.

Comment: I have no problem getting today's date on default.  But once the form is submitted through jquery (thecodemine.org) and the datepicker loads again, it doesn't show the date automatically.  Only after a date is clicked again.

Comment: Can't I just reload today's date again?

Comment: This code will load todays date in the box for you automatically on page load.

Comment: See, my page is not being reloaded.  I'm using jquery to show new content in the same div.  Please see www.thecodemine.org for one of their form samples.  They do not have a datepicker in the samples obviously.